# Sql grouping trouble

Tags: sql

I got in trouble with a sql script as this:

```
SELECT A, B, C,
 CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN '0<20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END AS E
 COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_X
GROUP BY A, B, C, D;
```

Resultset like this;

```
     A  B   C     D   count(*)
    CAR 1   2   21-50   1
    CAR 1   2   21-50   1
   BIKE 1   3   0-20    1
```

At first row is CAR has a D=25.So it is between 21-50.
And then second row is CAR has D=32.So it is between 21-50 too.

Shortly I want to resultset like above:

```
    A   B   C     D   count(*)
   CAR  1   2   21-50   2
  BIKE  1   3   0-20    1
```

So CAR must be 2 by grouping as using D column.

How can I assure this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're grouping by `D` first and only then applying the `case` logic. If you add `D` to the select list, you'd see results that probably look like this:

```
     A  B   C     D     E    count(*)
    CAR 1   2    20   21-50    1
    CAR 1   2    30   21-50    1
   BIKE 1   3     7    0-20    1
```

In order to avoid this, you could apply the `case` first and only then the `group by` clause, by using a subquery:

```
SELECT A, B, C, E, COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT A, B, C,
               CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN '0<20'
               WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
               WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
               ELSE '>101' END AS E
        FROM   TABLE_X) t
GROUP BY A, B, C, E;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query should work. Basically, I am just pulling the count(1) function and hence the group by clause to an outer query while leaving all the rest functionality to the inner query.

```
SELECT A,B,C,E, count(1) from
(
  SELECT A, B, C,
  CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN '0<20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END AS E
  FROM TABLE_X
)
GROUP BY A, B, C, E;
```

Comment: @shree.pat18: Its a typo. It should be E. Refer edit.

Comment: This is the approach I would have suggested, as it breaks the problem up into clearer steps. However, as @shree.pat18 has pointed out, the main (outer) select should be selecting `E`, not `D`.

Comment: @Turophile: Yeah.. It was a typo. Since you agree to it, you can consider upvoting!

Answer (score 1):

Group by the calculation for D, not D itself, like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C,
 CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN ' 0-20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END AS E
 ,COUNT(*) as "Coun"
 FROM TABLE_X
GROUP BY A, B, C, 
 CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN ' 0-20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END
```

yields this

```
A    B           C           E      Count
---- ----------- ----------- ------ -----------
BIKE 1           3            0-20  1
CAR  1           2           21-50  2
```

when run in SQL Server 2012 on a table loaded with these values:

```
values
     ('CAR', 1,2,22)
    ,('CAR', 1,2,23)
    ,('BIKE',1,3,2)
```

Comment: @volkan: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle Db.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below query:

```
SELECT A, B, C,
 CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN '0<20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END AS E
 COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_X
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

We use the SQL GROUP BY clause to group by relative position in the result set, where the first field in the result set is 1. The next field is 2, and so on.

Comment: I couldn't understand GROUP BY 1,2,3,4.If these were A, B, C, D, it couldn't work.

Comment: @volkan: Instead of using the field name, you are using the column position here.  I am hunting for the document reference. Will post soon.

Comment: @volkan: If it works, you can upvote and accept as answer. This probably avoids an outer query which all the other answers suggests.

Comment: @volkan: Using numbers in group by is related to concept called `ordinal numbers` in oracle. Not able to get documentation though :(